# Python PyQt5 movie splash screen

Tags: pyqt5, splash-screen, python-3.8

I wanted to have a .mp4 or .gif file as a splashscreen. I'm using Python 3.8 and PyQt5. I tried to do it myself but didn't succeed. Does any1 know how?

I tried this:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen, QApplication, QWidget


class MovieSplashScreen(QSplashScreen):

    def __init__(self, movie, parent=None):
        movie.jumpToFrame(0)
        pixmap = QPixmap(movie.frameRect().size())

        QSplashScreen.__init__(self, pixmap)
        self.movie = movie
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.repaint)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pixmap = self.movie.currentPixmap()
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    movie = QMovie("splash.gif")
    splash = MovieSplashScreen(movie)
    splash.show()

    start = time.time()

    while movie.state() == QMovie.Running and time.time() < start + 10:
        app.processEvents()

    window = QWidget()
    window.show()
    splash.finish(window)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the [`QMovie`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html):

```
# ...
splash.show()
splash.movie.start()
# ...
```

Comment: it works now. but how can I prevent it from beeing fullscreen?

Comment: @Moondancer I don't understand you, explain yourself better, how big is your .gif?

Comment: it is 1080x1920. Do I just have to lower the resolution?

Comment: I'd say that using a 1080x1920 video for a splash screen is not a very good idea. I hope that you resized the source video and you're not using real time processing for it, and that the video is not too long, otherwise you'll find yourself in the situation of having a splash screen that lasts too much due to the fact that it's processing the video (and that's not a very smart use of a splash screen, which should use less resources as possible).